# Caption package breaks tex4ht automatic sectioning pagination

Tags: captions, tex4ht, make4ht

The `caption` package seems to break automatic sectioning pagination in `tex4ht`. The document `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption, blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \part{Part One}
        \section{Section One}
        \blindtext
        \section{Section Two}
        \blindtext
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{\label{fig:mwe}Some Caption}
        \end{figure}
    \part{Part Two}
        \section{Section Three}
        \blindtext
        \section{Section Four}
        \blindtext
\end{document}
```

when compiled using

```
make4ht test.tex "xhtml,mathjax,3"
```

Generates `testpa1.html` correctly as expected

```
<body>
   <!-- l. 5 --><div class='crosslinks'><p class='noindent'>[<a href='Test1pa2.html'>next</a>] [<a href='#tailTest1pa1.html'>tail</a>] [<a href='Test1.html#Test1pa1.html'>up</a>] </p></div>
   <h1 class='partHead'><span class='titlemark'>Part I<br /></span><a id='x2-1000I'></a>Part One</h1>
   <div class='sectionTOCS'>
   <span class='sectionToc'>1 <a href='Test1se1.html#x3-20001'>Section One</a></span>
<br />   <span class='sectionToc'>2 <a href='Test1se2.html#x4-30002'>Section Two</a></span>
   </div>


   <!-- l. 14 --><div class='crosslinks'><p class='noindent'>[<a href='Test1pa2.html'>next</a>] [<a href='Test1pa1.html'>front</a>] [<a href='Test1.html#Test1pa1.html'>up</a>] </p></div>
<!-- l. 14 --><p class='indent'>   <a id='tailTest1pa1.html'></a> </p> 
</body>
```

but the file `testpa2.html` is missing the links to Sections Three and Four:

```
<body>
   <!-- l. 14 --><div class='crosslinks'><p class='noindent'>[<a href='Test1pa1.html'>prev</a>] [<a href='Test1pa1.html#tailTest1pa1.html'>prev-tail</a>] [<a href='#tailTest1pa2.html'>tail</a>] [<a href='Test1.html#Test1pa2.html'>up</a>] </p></div>
   <h1 class='partHead'><span class='titlemark'>Part II<br /></span><a id='x5-4000II'></a>Part Two</h1>
   <div class='sectionTOCS'>
   </div>


   <!-- l. 19 --><div class='crosslinks'><p class='noindent'>[<a href='Test1pa1.html'>prev</a>] [<a href='Test1pa1.html#tailTest1pa1.html'>prev-tail</a>] [<a href='Test1pa2.html'>front</a>] [<a href='Test1.html#Test1pa2.html'>up</a>] </p></div>
<!-- l. 19 --><p class='indent'>   <a id='tailTest1pa2.html'></a> </p> 
</body>
```

In a larger document with lots of parts and sections, things start going bad at the first instance of the `\caption` command and get worse from there.

If I remove either the `\caption` command or the `caption` package from the MWE, everything works as expected.

I have seen [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520996/110602), but the modification suggested in that answer seems to already be in `caption-hooks.4ht` in TL2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
 \renewcommand*\caption@@@addcontentsline[4]{%
   \def\temp{#1}\def\tempa{toc}\ifx \temp\tempa\else%
   \gHAdvance\TitleCount  1 %
   \fi%
   \addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{\protect\numberline{#3}{\detokenize{#4}}}%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\caption` command as defined by `caption`package adds figure caption to the table of figures. For some reason, this prevents printing of subsequent tables of contents after that point. It needs to step the `\TitleCount` counter to get it working.

It seems to work with this change:

[image]